# Mongoose $push - no errors when: inserting object with existing unique field + inserting trash

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, subdocument

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have an Array of Objects (the subdocument way: defined in a Schema) inside a main document, and I want this subdocument to behave as a document itself.

This is, when pushing an Object into the Subdocument Array, I would like  that it threw an error:

- if any of the `unique` fields of the object being inserted are already taken
- if the object being inserted doesn't match the `TemplateSchema`

This would be my main document:

```
var ApplicationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  },
  ...
  templates: {
    type: [TemplateSchema]
  }
});
```

and the following would be the subdocument, the `templates` field inside the `ApplicationSchema`:

```
var TemplateSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    sparse: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  },
  ...
});
```

In this case, when I am trying to:

1. add a new object with an already existing `name`, or
2. *push* any trash into my subdocument

it's happening that:

1. no error is being thrown about the duplicated field value
2. the trash object (i.e. `{some: "trash"}`) is being inserted - not
   really the object itself, but it's pushing an empty `template`
   object inside the `templates` array

and I can't figure out why.

Here is the query I'm using to insert new template objects into the `templates` array inside the main document, which I guess is here where it is not working as expected:

```
exports.create = function(id, objTemplate, callback) {
  ApplicationModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: id },
      {
        $push: {
          "templates": objTemplate
        }
      },
      {
        safe: true,
        upsert: true,
        new : true
      },
      function(err, application) {
        // handle stuff
      }
    );
};
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data

Comment: @AlokDeshwal do you mean an example of an object I would add to `templates`?

Comment: You don't want "unique" there as it creates an index that is "unique" across the collection and not just the array of that document. Instead you will want to that that the "name" property in the array does not contain the item you are adding. i.e `{ "_id": id, "templates.name": { "$ne":  objTemplate.name } }`. You also cannot mix this with "upsert" since you would end up creating a new document where the array element was not present. There are already answers here that deal with this.

Comment: Example of unique handling and upserts here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32447789/5031275

Comment: Thank you very much @BlakesSeven. As I am new to `mongo`, some aspects seem a bit hard to assimilate at the beginning and make things work as expected.

Comment: @BlakesSeven and why if I pass a trash object i.e. `{ some: "trash" }`, it's inserting it into the `templates` array? Shouldn't it be complaining for not folllowing the `TemplateSchema`?

Comment: Nope. The idea here is not "exceptions" as would be thrown by a duplicate key ( and as noted this does not apply here ) but rather to determine where nothing was updated due to the value already being present. Then you can basically report that you cannot update since that value exists when the modified count is `0`.